# Position of a dash dropdown inline with other components

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am using plotly Dash and i am having problems with the position of a dash component on the page. It’s the ‘change the year’ dropdown as shown in the picture below. I would like it to be where i show with the arrow, whereas it’s below my first radioitem component.
[image]

My code below:

```
external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets= external_stylesheets  )

# determining the layout of the page
app.layout = html.Div( [
    html.Div( [
        html.Label( ['Change continent:'],
                    style={'font-weight': 'bold', 'display': 'inline-block', 'justifyContent': 'center', 'width': '65%',
                           'height': '100%'},
                    ),

        dcc.RadioItems(
            id='radio_ITEMS',
            options=[
            {'label': 'AMERICA', 'value': 'graph1'},
            {'label': 'EUROPE', 'value': 'graph2'},
            {'label': 'ASIA', 'value': 'graph3'}],
            value='graph1',


        ),
    ], className='six columns' ),

    html.Div( [
            html.Label( ['Change the variable:'],
                        style={'font-weight': 'bold', 'display': 'inline-block', 'justifyContent': 'center', 'width': '65%',
                               'height': '100%'},
                        ),

            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='radio_items2',
                options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in cols1],
                value='Happiness Score',

            ),
        ], className='six columns' ),
    html.Div( [
        html.Label( ['Change the  year:'], style={'font-weight': 'bold', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Dropdown(id="drop",
                     options=[
                         {"label": "1970", "value": 2015},
                         {"label": "1980", "value": 2016},
                         {"label": "1990", "value": 2017},
                         {"label": "2000", "value": 2018},
                         {"label": "2010", "value": 2019}],
                     multi=False,
                     value=2015,
                     style={"width": "35%"},
                     )]),

    html.Div(
        dcc.Graph( id='the_graph',
                   style={'height': 600, 'width': 1000, }
                   ),
    ),
] ,className= 'fifteen columns')

@app.callback(
    Output( 'the_graph', 'figure' ),
    [Input( 'radio_ITEMS', 'value' ),
     Input( component_id='radio_items2', component_property='value' ),
     Input('drop', 'value')]
```

Answer (score 6):

As a rule of thumb, adjust the style of your app using `css`, not inline `style`.

The issue you're experiencing is that the width of your divs are in sum greater than 100% therefore making them span multiple rows. You can fix using the code provided below.

**Remove the styling from your code + use broad classes (specific ids if necessary):**

```
# determining the layout of the page
app.layout = html.Div( [
    html.Div(
        classname="my-cols",
        children = [
            html.Label('Change continent:'),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='radio_ITEMS',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'AMERICA', 'value': 'graph1'},
                    {'label': 'EUROPE', 'value': 'graph2'},
                    {'label': 'ASIA', 'value': 'graph3'}
                    ],
                value='graph1',
                ),
            ]
        ),
    html.Div(
        classname="my-cols",
        children = [
            html.Label('Change variable:'),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='radio_items2', # id naming should be consistent...
                options=[{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in cols1],
                value='Happiness Score',
                ),
            ]
        ),
    html.Div(
        classname="my-cols",
        children = [
            html.Label('Change year:'),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='radio_items2', # id naming should be consistent...
                options=[
                         {"label": "1970", "value": 2015},
                         {"label": "1980", "value": 2016},
                         {"label": "1990", "value": 2017},
                         {"label": "2000", "value": 2018},
                         {"label": "2010", "value": 2019}
                     ],
                multi=False,
                value='Happiness Score',
                ),
            ]
        ),
    html.Div(
        dcc.Graph(
            id='the_graph',
            ),
        )
) # close the app!
```

Create a css file in your project root – or create a folder in the root named `styles` and add a file in that folder. Name is arbitrary...

```css
.my-cols{
  width: calc(100%/3);
  float: left;
}

/* The following formats the content whose id = the_graph*/
@the_graph{
  height: 600;
  width: 1000
}

/* Style all labels*/
label{
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  /* I don't think you need these style configs... (justify, w, h)...*/
  justifyContent: center;
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

*This should solve your problem.*

Comment: Good answer. Side note for future readers: Using a separate .css file is the way to go, however, unfortunately, there are some tools in corporate environments that only allow a single file. In this case, defining the style in the same file is the only option, not nice, but usable.